# How is this absolute inequality correct and belongs to the real number set?

Tags: calculus, inequality

I have been practicing some questions and I find them easy, but this one can't get through... how does an absolute equation can equal to a negative number?

The equation is:

|5x - 8| >= -1

And the answer is: R 
Meaning that it belongs to the real numbers set.

Comment: As $|y|>0\geqslant -1$ your inequality is always true. Still I don't understand your question. Especially what you mean with the last sentence.

Comment: I am asking how could an inequality be equal to -1, true it is higher than -1 but not equal

Comment: So?  If $3>2$ is true, then $3\geqslant 2$ is also true. Does that mean $3=2$?

Comment: That's what I said, but my professor said no you have to think about it.. I have finished but this, I got stuck on because of what he said

Comment: it is not the inequality that is equal to $-1$. The symbol $>=$ stands for $\ge$ which means that what is written on the left-hand side (a positive number) is **greater or equal** than what is written on the right-hand side (a negative number).

Comment: The inequality given is certainly not what we might call sharp - there is no limit point or value giving equality. But a weak inequality is still true, even if a stronger one is true too. This is, in fact, often useful - because sometimes it is only necessary to prove a weak inequality for the application we have in mind, and this can mean we can take short cuts and use simplifying estimates to speed up the work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When not writing in LaTeX, then $>=$ can be an easy-to-type replacement for $\geq$. In most contexts, it would make no sense to really mean a $>$ followed by a $=$, since that would not give any well-formed term whatsoever[1].

Thus, we are looking are the inequality:
$$|5x-8| \geq -1$$

As the absolute value is always non-negative, it is always greater-or-equal[2] than $-1$, hence the solution set for this inequality is $\mathbb{R}$.

Footnote:

[1]: One exception might be if we want to **define** the relation $>$ as a set, but this is probably not relevant for the OP for quite some time.

[2]: The mathematical "A or B" means that at least one of A and B is true. As for any mathematical statement, it says what it says and no more: In particular, we cannot infer that we really need to mention both. Since $|x| \geq -1$ is equivalent to $|x| > -1$ or $|x| = -1$ and the former is always true, the or is given. We do not care about the useless second case.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, my professor confused me with an equation this simple..

Comment: @Khalid If my explanation resolved the confusion, please feel free to upvote and accept.